# How to take screenshot of visible area of horizontalscrollview in android?

Tags: android, view, screenshot, horizontalscrollview

I am working on an android app and I want to take screenshot of a visible area of horizontalscrollview. I am using below code for that :-

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {

        /*Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 
                mDiviceWidth , view.getHeight());*/

        /*Rect rect = new Rect(view.getScrollX(), 0, 
                view.getScrollX() + mDiviceWidth , view.getHeight());*/

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    //  view.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
    //  view.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
    //  view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds);
    //  view.getGlobalVisibleRect(scrollBounds);
        view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(scrollBounds);
        Log.e("X Scrolled", ""+view.getScrollX());
        Log.e("left", ""+scrollBounds.left);
        Log.e("right", ""+scrollBounds.right);
        Log.e("top", ""+scrollBounds.top);
        Log.e("bottom", ""+scrollBounds.bottom);
        /*view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();*/
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

        /*float left,right,top,bottom;

        left = view.getLeft();
        right =   mDiviceWidth;
        top = 0;
        bottom = view.getHeight();*/

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    //  canvas.clipRect(left, top, 
    //          right , bottom);
        canvas.clipRect(scrollBounds);
        view.draw(canvas);
    //  view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;

    }
```

Above code is taking the screenshot but returning wrong area. Some times it captures visible area but sometimes it captures the random area  which is not visible or partial visible. I have already used

```
//  view.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
//  view.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
//  view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds);
//  view.getGlobalVisibleRect(scrollBounds);
```

methods but not getting the perfect result.

So please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    return b;
}
```